# Adding a group in a constructor instead of only one

Tags: java

Sorry if I'm a bit vague, but between not being my native language and that I am a beginner, I'm trying my best to put the question clear.

I am stuck in a part of an exercise that I can't find any solutions to, even after searching in Google. At least not something that I understand.

I have to create two constructors, one of them, apart from the variables, receives a group of teachers, and the other one receives only one teacher.

```
private Set<Teacher> teacher;

public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher teacher) {
    super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);
    this.teacher = new HashSet<Teacher>();
}
```

I can't find anything about how to make them different, so that one constructor only adds 1 teacher, and the other one adds a few teachers. Thanks for the help, would be lovely if you linked some resources too.

Comment: Just write the second one.

Comment: Use Constructor Overloading for creating two constructor

Comment: `List<Teacher> teachers` to add more then one teacher.

Comment: @atishshimpi So instead of Teacher teacher in the constructor, the List thing? And also then inside, this.teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();

Comment: Does your assignment say what the "group" of teachers should be? I see you define a `Set` as a private variable. Are you supposed to get a `Set` of teachers? a `List`? Any kind of `Collection`? Array?

Comment: Is it required to use `Set` and also do you know the number of `Teachers`?

Comment: Yes, Set is required. And I need to use the teachers list later in the class, validating if they are actually teachers and etc. Sorry if my vocabulary is not on point.

Comment: @BrickTop I have shown in answer section how to pass single teacher and multiple teachers to two different constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested, you should use constructor overloading.

Java knows which constructor of the two to use because their parameters are different. So you can make two different constructors, and it's OK as long as the types or the number of parameters are different.

In your case the number of parameters is the same, but the type of the last parameter is different. For one constructor, the type is `Teacher`, and for the other `Set<Teacher>`. So it's legal to write this in Java.

So, for example:

```
private Set<Teacher> teacher;

// Constructor with only one teacher.

public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher teacher) {
    super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);
    this.teacher = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    this.teacher.add( teacher );
}

// Constructor with a set of teachers.

public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Set<Teacher> teachers) {
    super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);
    this.teacher = new HashSet<Teacher>(teachers);
}
```

You could actually assign `teachers` directly to `this.teacher`, but I chose to show copying in, under the assumption that you may need to use the set you passed as parameters for something else and you don't want the private set to be affected by it.

So now, if you call:

```
new DespachoImpl( "XXXX", 5, 8, new Teacher(....) );
```

It will call the first constructor. But if you call:

```
Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
teachers.add( new Teacher(...));
teachers.add( new Teacher(...));

new DespachoImpl( "XXXX", 5, 8, teachers );
```

It will call the second constructor.

Comment: But you will be able to create an instance with no teachers, which is not correct.

Comment: @ZouZou I didn't see that the OP requested that the set of teachers not be empty, only that a `Set` of teachers is required. If it needs to be checked for emptiness, that can be added to the constructor, and then an Exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If you at least requires one Teacher (and others can be optional), i.e a one to many relation, you don't need two constructors. One is sufficient with a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter.

```
public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher required, Teacher... moreTeachers) {
    super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);
    this.teacher = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    this.teacher.add(required);
    this.teacher.addAll(Arrays.asList(moreTeachers));
}
```

Comment: As for the exercise, I need two.

Comment: Isn't the `required` redundant? `Teacher... teachers` should be enough on its own.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja No because you would be able to create a `DespachoImpl` object with no teachers. I assumed that it requires at least one teacher.

Comment: @BrickTop This seems like an unecessary requirement. Why would you add two constructors, if you can do it with one?

Comment: @ZouZou Not sure, that's what's written on the paper. And that's why I can't figure out how to make the two constructors add 1/2+ to the same list being different. How do specify that one of them is only used when only one Teacher is added to the list and the other one when a few Teacher are added?

Answer (score 1):

You could get an arbitrary amount of Teachers, and then check if the amount of Teachers is at least 1:

```
private Set<Teacher> teachers;

public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher... teachers) {
    super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);

    if (teachers.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No teachers given");
    }

    this.teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    this.teachers.addAll(Arrays.asList(teachers));
}
```

If two constructors are a requirement, then this is a way of doing it:

```
private Set<Teacher> teachers;

public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher teacher) {
    this(nombre, planta, aforo, new Teacher[] { teacher });
}

public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher[] teachers) {
    super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);

    if (teachers.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No teachers given");
    }

    this.teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    this.teachers.addAll(Arrays.asList(teachers));
}
```

This seems very stupid to me, but it's necessary for the first constructor to be able to call the second one. Other than that, It's an equally solid solution as the first one.

Comment: IMO this is better to add the required Teacher as parameter. You'll  get an error at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: That is what I thought, problem is, I need two constructors, not one.

Comment: @ZouZou IMO giving no teachers to the constructor is a programmer error, which is exactly what runtime errors are for.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Then why would you catch this at runtime if you could do it a compile time ? (which would also mean that this is a programmer error)

Comment: @ZouZou because this is a much cleaner way than requiring to Teachers, one being a single instance and one being an array or collection.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja So basically you are saying it's a much cleaner way to allow the programmer to construct illegal instances at compile time and detect it at runtime? This is a bad OO approach IMO, but that's your opinion.

Comment: @ZouZou That's not what I meant. I meant that instead of having to call `MyClass(teacher, otherTeachers)` I can call `MyClass(allTeachers)`. You are right in that compile-time errors are preferred to runtime-errors generally, but I don't think that making this a compile-error would justify having bizarre constructors. If the runtime-error is sensical, it's just as informative as a compile error is.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja That's all the point of using varargs. There will be no differences for the caller. He can either write `new MyClass(teacherOne)` or `new MyClass(teacherOne, teacherTwo, teacherThree, etc.)`. There is no bizarre constructor.

Comment: @ZouZou But he cannot do `new MyClass(teachers)` where `teachers` is an array.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Well that would mean you would be able to pass an empty array (even if you check the length at runtime). Well I don't think there is a need to pollute your answer with all our comments.  You have your opinion and I have mine. I think this is the standard way to do it when you have this kinds of requirement (i.e a many to one relationship).

Comment: @ZouZou Agree to disagree, then :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to try constructor overloading..

```
public class Teacher
{
    public Teacher(string teacherName)
    {
        // Add single teacher
    }

    public Teacher(List<string> teacherNames)
    {
        // Add multiple teachers
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: OP is not definining the `Teacher` class. It is a given. The requirement is to have two constructors of the `DespachoImpl` class, to judge from OP's source.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two constructors, one of them, apart from the variables, receives a group of teachers as a `List<Teacher> teachers`, and the other one receives only one teacher object.

```
private Set<Teacher> teacher;
```

Adding single Teacher object into set.

```
 public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo,Teacher teacher) {  
        super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);  
         this.teacher = new HashSet<Teacher>();  
         this.teacher.add(teacher);      
 }
```

Adding List of teachers into set.

```
 public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo,List<Teacher> teachers) {  
        super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);   
        this.teacher = new HashSet<Teacher>(teachers);  
 }
```

or you can pass multiple teachers as variable arguments

```
public DespachoImpl(String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo, Teacher... teachers) {
        super(TipoLugar.OTRO, nombre, planta, aforo);
        this.teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
        this.teachers.addAll(Arrays.asList(teachers));
    }
```